# How can I separate a string and turn it into variables

Tags: python

Basically, I want to separate a string and then turn every separate into a variable.

For example: If I have a string `x = "2 4 6 8"` how can I turn it into this: `a = 2`
`b = 4`
`c = 6`
`d = 8`

Thanks,

Comment: Use a container: `l = x.split()`

Comment: You can create a list like this ~> `[int(el) for el in x.split(' ')]`

Comment: `a,b,c,d = map(int, x.split())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't generate variables dynamically, use a container.

The best is probably a list:

```
l = [int(e) for e in x.split()]
```

output: `[2, 4, 6, 8]`

If you really want named keys, use a dictionary:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

x = "2 4 6 8"

d = dict(zip(ascii_lowercase, map(int, x.split())))
```

output: `{'a': 2, 'b': 4, 'c': 6, 'd': 8}`

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want actual integers, not the string representation?

```
aslist = map(int, x.split())
a, b, c, d = aslist
```